# Angular, How to pass value from HTML template to component without change detection problems

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm having issues trying to retrieve a value from an HTML template to do calculations with; however, I am finding no good solutions. When I add a method into the `*ngFor` template it causes horrible change detection problems and the method is called 100's of times. I also cannot use property binding since it's within the same component and not a child. I am iteration through a large JSON array of objects and need to find the `issueNumber` of each and call a new service.
Below is an example of how I did it with change detection issues.
This may be a simple solution, but It's beating me up.

Thanks all.

**HTML**

```
 <div *ngFor="let m of issues"> 
  .....
 {{findAdditionalIssues(m.issueNumber)}}

  .....
 </div
```

**Component**

```
  findAdditionalIssues(issueNumber: any)
  {
   callnewservice.get(issueNumber).subscribe ()
  }
```

Comment: Can't you iterate over the artay in the ts file and only then display it in the view?

Comment: Fetch the "additional issues" beforehand, and display the array instead of calling the findAdditionalIssues inside the template

Answer (score 1):

Then it's better to select all the `issueNumber` out, and then for each of them, call the `callnewservice.get()`. You can use a [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) to fire all these requests in parallel, and the subscriber will wait for **ALL** the results to come back before emitting a resonponse.

```
forkJoin[issues.select(m => callnewservice.get(m.issueNumber))]
  .subscribe(additionalIssues => console.log(additionalIssues))
```

forkJoin descriptions:

> This operator is best used when you have a group of observables and only care about the final emitted value of each. One common use case for this is if you wish to issue multiple requests on page load (or some other event) and only want to take action when a response has been received for all. In this way it is similar to how you might use Promise.all.